# Facebook graph web API not returning response as JSON

Tags: python, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I read the [documentation of Facebook graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api) and trying to get the results from the oauth endpoint. The url I'm requesting is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=<MY_CLIENT_ID>&client_secret=<MY_CLIENT_SECRET>&redirect_uri=<MY_REDIRECT_URL>&code=<CODE_RECEIVED_FROM_FB>
```

but I get a response like this:

```
access_token=CAAICzAsj0CgBAAQ7Go1k4NuG89mabLg6ZCpGoBoZCelRsLdQlcq1yvUbFZAKZBskTwMVmkTeZBZC9Thd4keYq0d3er3tGNTZCzR3TMnfEZABVfOpBqkOZBvZANZCny3XrDPDv7bTZB4ZAYjcPfvvMA4gRTcPrRJhht6XjIehV5gLtXW4YRvWaL4KuhYWB&expires=5169000
```

This happens from python requests library and also when I use curl from terminal or open in browser. Looks like it's returning response in form of get parameters. Why is it not returning JSON as documented? What's going on?

Comment: The Graph API returns JSON. The oauth endpoint doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, my mistake, this is related to FB Graph API version. When I added the version as defined in the api, it worked fine.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token...
```

Reference:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow